# Should I use "a" or "the" for "issue" when I first mention it in a paragraph? Do I need article for "selectivity"?

Tags: articles

I am writing a technical report and need some help for verifying the very first sentence:

"This report presents an effective approach to mitigating ***the*** prolonged issue of ***the*** insufficient wet etching selectivity between metal and oxide."

For the first ***the***, should I use "***a***" instead?

For the second ***the***, can I omit it? Does "selectivity" require an article?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks much for reading my question. I believe most of the posts here came in when people have troubles in preparing some sorts of documents or presentations. I was not sure about the correct way to use the article so I tried to provide the information as much as possible. Of course, I don't have to mention that I am writing a report and in that way would you think this is not a "proof-reading" question instead?

Thanks again for reading. I still think this is an appropriate question to ask in such a "English Language & USAGE" forum.

Answer (score -1):

Is there only one issue of insufficient wet etching selectivity? If so the first "*the*" is correct. If there are more than one issue, use "*a*".

If the insufficiency of wet etching is a widely known specific problem known to the readers you could use the second "*the*" as a demonstrative reference to the problem. Otherwise, omit it.

This answer is consistent with a good summary that appears in

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/definite-article-the